# Why can't I find DataTemplates in merged resource dictionaries?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

In my MainWindow.xaml, I have the following reference to a ResourceDictionary:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

In MainSkin.xaml, I define a datatemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TagTemplate">
   ...
</DataTemplate>
```

Deeper within my application, I attempt to use this data template:

```
<ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Tag}" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource TagTemplate}"/>
```

The code compiles successfully, but when I attempt to load a Page or UserControl that contains this StaticResource, I get an exception saying that the TagTemplate can't be found.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try referencing it as a DynamicResource

Comment: @Dan If I change it to DynamicResource, it works, but why? I've seen several different examples that show StaticResource working in this situation -- unless those examples are buggy, too.

Comment: Hi. I was going to ask the same question myself. But the answer here is good. Is there any chance you could give links to some of those resources where you found these examples. I am just learning XAML and am very interested in "daisy chaining" XAML resource dictionaries like this in my current projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the contents of a resource defined in a XAML file, you need to "include" that XAML file in each page and control that uses it. So every XAML files will need to have the `MergedDictionaries` entry that you have in MainWindow.xaml.

Alternatively you can add those merge dictionaries to `App.xaml` and those resources are included implicitly:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MainSkin.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: So UserControls or DataTemplates used inside my MainWindow don't have access to items defined in a merged dictionary referenced in MainWindow's Window.Resources section? I have to go up one level to the Application Resources instead?

Comment: Yes, the resources that defined in a resource dictionary in a control are only accessible to that control/page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using that StaticResource in the same Window where it is declared? Otherwise I think that you cannot have access to that.

Comment: Yes. I'm using the ContentControl in Page displayed within a Frame on MainWindow.